# Lazy loading of divs in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page with big count of divs such as:

```
<div class="post">
<table>
  <tr> <td><%= post.title %> </td> </tr>

  <tr><td colspan="4"><iframe width="370" height="210" 
  src= "<%= post.url %>"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td> </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

How can I add lazy loading to this page?

I used ***jquery-lazyload-any***.

I place js to ***/vendor/assets/javascripts***

And to ***/app/assets/javascripts/application.js*** add this code

```
//= require jquery.lazyload-any

function load(img)
{
  img.fadeOut(0, function() {
  img.fadeIn(1000);
  });
}
$('.post').lazyload({load: load});
```

But nothing happend

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joakimk/1852580

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this js https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt#support-video-tag

And put in application.html.erb

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag('jquery.lazyloadxt.extra.js') %>
```

And this to config/initializer/assets.rb

```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.lazyloadxt.extra.js )
```